# React - How to make a modal component that I can call from anywhere?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a fairly sophisticated app with a main layout component, several different pages, each page having its own specialized components. I want to be able to call up a `<Modal />` component from anywhere.

Currently, my solution probably isn't so hot. I have a `<Modal />` in the `Layout` component at the very top. So the layout is sending modal props (visible, message, buttons) down through every component so that any page or component can trigger a modal. It feels a bit wrong and messy though.

Is there another way? Maybe I can use `React.cloneElement` somehow, pass it some props (including a callback to handle button click)? Or do I just have a hidden `<Modal />` on every page or component that needs to invoke one?

Comment: Have a look at PubSub or similar event systems: https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

Answer (score 3):

You should invest in the Flux architecture for this one. You can then trigger an action from anywhere and have the modal pop through a property from the store.

Some pseudo code below

```
class Store {

   constructor() {
     this.registerAction('showModal', setModalVisibility);
   }
   setModalVisiblity(showModal) {
      this.setState({showModal: showModal});
   }
}

class Action {
    showModal(showModal) {
       return showModal;
    }
}

class MyOtherComponent {
   render() {
     return (<div onClick={someFluxInstance.getActions().showModal}>Click</div>
   }
}

class Layout {
  render() {
    if(this.props.showModal) {
      <Modal />
    }
  }
}
```